# How do I access items in a nested array, from an external JS file, in a For Loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, object, module

I am working on my own website that acts as a CV and portfolio, a fun way to display my web design skills. The aim of it is to use JavaScript to populate the webpage with each of my jobs, key skills, qualifications, etc. from arrays used as a database.

In my head section, I added two script tags

```
<script type="module" src="js/database_career.js" defer></script>
<script type="module" src="js/script.js" defer></script>
```

In the database_career.js file, I created a class constructor with the job details as its object properties

```
function Job(title,company,location,date,summary,details) {
  this.title = title;
  this.company = company;
  this.location = location;
  this.date = date;
  this.summary = summary;
  this.details = details;
}
```

And in that same file, here's (a sample of) an array of all the jobs I want to populate my web page with.

```
const JOBS = [
  new Job(
    "Job Title",
    "Company",
    "Location",
    "Month 20XX ~ Now",
    "Insert Job Summary Here",
    ["Bullet Point for notable task or accomplishment 1",
    "Bullet Point for notable task or accomplishment 2",
    "Bullet Point for notable task or accomplishment 3"]
  ),
  new Job()
];
```

Now here's what I coded in the main script.js file so far.

```
    import JOBS from "./database_career.js";
        
            // Populate the Career Section
            const myCareer = document.querySelector("#work");
              const jobSection = document.createElement("div");
                jobSection.classList.add("content-wrap", "clearfix");
            
                const jobsHeading = document.createElement("h2");
                const jobsHeading_content = `<i class="fas fa-briefcase" aria-hidden="true"></i>Work Experience`;
                jobsHeading.innerHTML = jobsHeading_content;
                jobSection.append(jobsHeading);
        
        for (let i=0;i<JOBS.length;i++) {
                const jobEntry = document.createElement("div");
                  jobEntry.classList.add("entry");
        
                const jobContent_narrow = `
                  <div class="col-narrow">
                    <h3>${JOBS[i].title}</h3>
                    <p class="uppercase">${JOBS[i].company}, ${JOBS[i].location}</p>
                    <p>${JOBS[i].date}</p>
                  </div>`;
        
        const jobContent_wide = `
                  <div class="col-wide description">
                  <p>${JOBS[i].summary}</p>`;
        
// Here's where I'm stuck. 
// I managed to get the rest of the job details, shown above, displaying correctly.
// I want to show the extra details in an unordered list but I was unable to access
// any individual items in the details array

// I could only show the full array itself but
// manipulating the array itself seems to be impossible
// I keep getting the following error
// script.js:49 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length') at script.js:49:42

        const jobDetails = document.createElement("ul");
          for (let e=0;e<JOBS[i].details.length;e++) {
            let listItem = document.createElement("li");
            let item = `<li>${JOBS[i].details[e]}</li>`;
            jobDetails.append(item);
          }
        
                const jobDetails_end = `
                </div>`;
        
                jobEntry.innerHTML = jobContent_narrow + jobContent_wide + jobDetails_end;
                jobSection.append(jobEntry);
              }
        
            myCareer.append(jobSection);
```

In case you missed the comments, I'm trying to add items from the details array contained in each job as bullet points in an unordered list but have been unable to access them directly. Instead I could display the full array itself.

Any help and advice would be much appreciated and I'll provide any further information if needed.

Thanks.

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.
Please remove all the module stuff and just have the loop and the HTML that is relevant

Comment: Also EITHER use innerHTML OR appendChild. You can do the whole lot using string literals so why the createElement ?

Answer (score 0):

I see your function initializes the details as this.details, so it could potentially be initialized as undefined if you don't pass that parameter.

Are you sure every single job has details? even as empty array lists?

The error thrown tells you he's trying to get the length of details of every job in the first loop, but got undefined, and calling undefined.length throws that exception

Comment: I can assure you, I have passed that array as the details property. I checked it. The Jobs array itself isn't finished, the first one is just a sample and the empty one's a placeholder.

Comment: If you're unsure of answer write comments instead to ask for details.

Comment: yeah, unfortunately i'm newly registered and couldn't comment yet. Now I can!

@mereMolf you could console log the JOBS[i].details inside the first iteration and before the second iteration, to be sure

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the problem is caused by the following line on `database_career.js`:

```
  ),
  new Job() // <---
];
```

where you instantiate a new job with `details` set to `undefined`.
Therefore the following line:

```js
for (let e=0;e<JOBS[i].details.length;e++)
```

is not safe to call because `.length` does not exist on `undefined` fields.

---

What I would recommend is to change this function to something like:

```js
function Job({ title, company, location, date, summary, details = [] } = {}) {
// ...
```

This uses the [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and [default parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters) (check the docs to learn more about them and see which browsers are supported) and would allow to have something like:

```
const JOBS = [
  new Job({
    title: "Job title",
    company: "Job company",
    // ...
    details: ["1", "2"]
  }),
  new Job(),
];
```

where `job.details` will always be initialised to an empty array and therefore will be safe to loop without explicitly checking for `undefined` first.

Another thing that I would recommend is to refactor `js/script.js` and create some small reusable functions, e.g.

```js
function render() {
  // ..
  for (let i=0; i< JOBS.length;i++ ) {
    renderJob(JOBS[i]);
  }
}

function renderJob(job) {
  // ...
  renderJobDetails(job.details);
}

function renderJobDetails(details) {
 // ...
}

render();
```

to improve readability.

If you get stuck again you might want to have a look at this article:

https://javascript.info/debugging-chrome

to learn how to use the browser debugger tool and better understand why your code does not work as expected.

Comment: `,  new Job(),` is obviously to show there is more than one Job in the array. Read the other comment: `the first one is just a sample and the empty one's a placeholder. `

Comment: @mplungjan thanks for your comment. It's hard to tell without the original source why the OP is getting the following error `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')`, but my guess is that they have an undefined array in the job collection, so that I think that this answer still applies, because with default parameters the nested array won't be `undefined`, unless when it's explicitly set to `null` in the constructor.

Answer (score -1):

You can nest the template literals

```
<ul>${job.details.map(detail => `<li>${detail}</li>`).join("")}</ul>
```

like this

```js
document.querySelector("#work").innerHTML = `
  <div class="content-wrap clearfix">
    <h2><i class="fas fa-briefcase" aria-hidden="true"></i>Work Experience</h2>
  ${JOBS.map(job => `
    <div class="entry">
      <div class="col-narrow">
        <h3>${job.title}</h3>
        <p class="uppercase">${job.company}, ${job.location}</p>
        <p>${job.date}</p>
      </div><div class="col-wide description">
        <p>${job.summary}</p>
        <ul>${job.details.map(detail => `<li>${detail}</li>`).join("")}</ul>
      </div>
    </div>`).join("")}
  </div>`
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-KfkfwYDsLkIlwQp6LFnl8zNdLGxu9YAA1QvwINks4PhcElQSvqcyVLLD9aMhXd13uQjoXtEKNosOWaZqXgel0g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />


<div id="work"></div>

<script>
function Job(title, company, location, date, summary, details) {
  this.title = title;
  this.company = company;
  this.location = location;
  this.date = date;
  this.summary = summary;
  this.details = details;
}


const JOBS = [
  new Job(
    "Job Title",
    "Company",
    "Location",
    "Month 20XX ~ Now",
    "Insert Job Summary Here", ["Bullet Point for notable task or accomplishment 1",
      "Bullet Point for notable task or accomplishment 2",
      "Bullet Point for notable task or accomplishment 3"
    ]
  ),
  new Job(
    "Job Title",
    "Company",
    "Location",
    "Month 20XX ~ Now",
    "Insert Job Summary Here", ["Bullet Point for notable task or accomplishment 1",
      "Bullet Point for notable task or accomplishment 2",
      "Bullet Point for notable task or accomplishment 3"
    ]
  ),

];
</script>
```